# Looking for a yum package repository containing apache subversion

Tags: rhel, yum, subversion

I'd like to be able to install Apache Subversion on Red Hat with yum.  Can anyone recommend a package repository?

Comment: You need to explain why `yum install subversion` won't work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there something you wouldn't be getting with the Subversion package in the default channel? [Step-by-step guide to installing subversion on RHEL](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-svn-subversion-server-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)